# SQL Query Between Two Strings

Tags: sql-server

I need Records between two strings passing through Parameters. @startString and @end String.
Between Query is possible between in these two strings?

```
10-00-000-000000 and 12-02-023-000000
```

Comment: Sure, you can do it but whether the results are what you expect is a different matter. What have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: Is your start and end string is datetime or date or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your column with Column1

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONVERT(BIGINT,REPLACE(@Column1,'-','')) BETWEEN 
CONVERT(BIGINT,REPLACE(@startString,'-','')) AND 
CONVERT(BIGINT,REPLACE(@endString,'-',''))
```

Comment: @RanaAli This approach is very erronous (if you are not absolutely sure that the format is the same). With many rows it will be very slow due to the heavy string and cast operations. And read about [sargable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable). You should avoid to do computations on the columns you are ussing in `where` or `join` or other places, where indexes might to an important job...

Answer (score 0):

If your strings `10-00-000-000000` and `12-02-023-000000` are **always** in the same format `xx-xx-xxx-xxxxxx` (2-2-3-6 numbers) you can compare them on alphanumeric base just using

```
WHERE YourColumn BETWEEN @startString AND @endString
```

I'm assuming, that `YourColumn` is a string column with exactly the same format.

But if the numbering/format might differ you first have to specify *What is the implicit sort order?* Is `10-90-...` higher or lower than `10-100-...` ?